# LUIS Add Utterance in code JSON POST failing

Tags: c#, json, azure-language-understanding

Following this example:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/luis/luis-quickstart-cs-add-utterance

I am trying to send an utterance to my LUIS App.
It keeps on failing with this response message:

```
{
  "error": {
    "code": "BadArgument",
    "message": "Failed to parse example labeling objects. Parameter name: exampleLabelObjects"
  }
}
```

My input body is:

```
{
  "text": "hi, what can I help you with?",
  "intentName": "Help",
  "entityLabels": []
}
```

And according too the link if you send an utterance without any entity labels the above is correct.

> The entityLabels field is required. If you don't want to label any
>   entities, provide an empty list as shown in the following example:

```
[
    {
        "text": "go to Seattle",
        "intentName": "BookFlight",
        "entityLabels": [
            {
                "entityName": "Location::LocationTo",
                "startCharIndex": 6,
                "endCharIndex": 12
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "text": "book a flight",
        "intentName": "BookFlight",
        "entityLabels": []
    }
]
```

The C# to build the object is as follows:

```
public class LUISUtterItem
    {
        public string utterances;
        public string text;
        public string intentName;
        public List<exampleLabelObjects> entityLabels;

    }

    public class exampleLabelObjects
    {
        public string entityName;
        public int startCharIndex;
        public int endCharIndex;
    }
```

I call it using:

```
LUISUtterItem itm = new LUISUtterItem(); 

            //itm.utterances = materialArray[1];
            itm.text = materialArray[1];
            itm.intentName = materialArray[2];
            itm.entityLabels = new List<exampleLabelObjects>();
```

I have also tried not including an "entityLabels" object, as well as a string list that just gets initiated with the same result.

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

So it seems like all you have to include in the body is "[]" around it and it worked:

```
[{
  "text": "hi, what can I help you with?",
  "intentName": "Help",
  "entityLabels": []
}]
```

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue. Solved by sending the body as:
{
  "text": "hi",
  "intentName": "Greetings"
}

Don't put entityLabel if it is not needed.